# JQGrid - Can the paging bar ask how many rows to show?

Tags: jqgrid, paging, row-number

I've been searching google trying to find out if the JQGrid paging bar has the ability to show something like

```
# Rows: 10 20 25 50 100
```

automatically built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  It's

```
rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50]
```